# Multiple overlay/intersection geoprocessing

Tags: qgis, pyqgis, overlay, overlapping-features

Is there any GIS function which gives back the polygons of the intersections by storing the number of the overlapping surfaces to an attribute?

Or do you have a script for this purpose?

A sample pic with transparency:

[image]

Comment: Do you want the geometry of the intersections or are you talking about recording a reference to intersecting polygons such as [ID=1,ID=4,ID=5],[ID=4,ID=9] etc....

Comment: I would like some layers with different levels of intersections. 
Or I prefer one layer where the intersecting features have the level of intersection in a field.

Comment: Are you trying to achieve something similar to what's explained in this [ESRI blog](https://blogs.esri.com/esri/arcgis/2012/11/13/spaghetti_and_meatballs/) ?

Comment: Interesting, thanks for the link. Actually I started to write a PyQGIS code, because I prefer open-source solutions.

Comment: I know, but are you trying to process your data to reach the same result?

Comment: Could you share your solution?

Comment: I cannot share, because of post-project legal conditions.

Answer (score 1):

I used the following workflow to obtain results similar to what you seem to be looking for:

1. Run the **Intersection** tool and select the same layer for the *Input* and *Intersect* layer.
2. Run the **Delete duplicate geometries** tool as the output from *Step 1* will produce annoying duplicates.
3. Run the **Join attributes by location** tool and select the output layer from *Step 2* as both input layers:

   [image: Join attributes by location]

   This step creates a `count` field which will contain the number of intersections for each polygon. However, if no polygon is being intersected, it will count as `1` so we need to subtract this in the next step.
4. Run the **Field Calculator** and update the `count` field using the expression:

   ```
   "count" - 1
   ```

---

I used the workflow and seem to get reasonably correct results:

Example 1:

[image: Count of 2]

Example 2:

[image: Count of 5]

---

If you don't wan to do the above steps manually, you could create a model such as this one:

[image: Model]

Or you can [download](http://www.filedropper.com/example_2) it and copy it to your `/.qgis2/processing/models` folder).

Comment: Thanks for your efforts Joseph, but I cannot accept it, since it gives only a similar result, that I want. I have to highlight those areas which are only covered by one polygon, covered by two polygon, and so forth.

Comment: @pnz - No problem at all, will keep it posted in case it might help others :)